# Algorithm to get the current week number (not ISO)

Tags: python, datetime

I'm looking for an easy way to get the current week number of the year in Python. I'm well aware of the datetime.datetime.isocalendar() function in the standard library, but this function stipulates that week 1 is the first Monday of the new year. My dilemma is that I'm using Sunday as a starting point for each week, and if Sunday is for example December 27 and January 1st appears at some point during that week, I need to represent that week as week 1 (and year 2015).

I thought of doing something like (pseudocode):

```
if (Jan 1) - (current_sunday) < 7 days:
    week_num = 1
```

And then storing that week number somewhere to iterate over next week. However, I feel that this is a very hackish method and would prefer something cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

Generally to get the current week number (starts from Sunday):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import calendar
>>> today = datetime.date.today())
>>> (int(today.strftime('%U')) + (datetime.date(today.year+1, 1, 1).weekday() != calendar.SUNDAY)) % 53
12
```

From the documentation of `strftime('%U')`:

> "Week number of the year (Sunday as the first day of the week) as a decimal number [00,53]. All days in a new year preceding the first Sunday are considered to be in week 0."

Hence the modified code for your specific requirements. There isn't really a non-hacky way to do what you want.

Comment: +1. you could also `import time; time.strftime('%U')`. OP wants `this number + 1`

Comment: This is sort of what I'm looking for, but not quite. I need to think from a week-to-week basis, without "partial" weeks. Sunday December 28 2014 using your code would give me 52, but since the year crosses over on that week, I want it to be 1.

Comment: 2017-01-01 is Sunday and `%U` returns `1` instead of `0`. The formula could be `%U + (1st Jan is not Sun)`: `(date(today.year,1,1).weekday() != calendar.SUNDAY)`

Comment: @JonMartin: `(%U modulo 52) + (1st Jan is not Sun)`

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian how would I convert that psuedocode to working Python that I could add to my answer?

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: What do you mean by (1st Jan is not Sun)?

Comment: `int(today.strftime('%U')) % 52 + (date(today.year,1,1).weekday() != calendar.SUNDAY)`

Comment: @JonMartin See edits. That seems to fit your needs now.

Comment: @J.F Sebastian Yeah that's what I thought. Literally only just remembered that boolean values are exactly the same as integers 1 and 0 in Python.

Comment: note: 2000/12/31 is the 2nd week by that formula i.e., further tweaks are required

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian Is that now fully functional? I'm doing this for me as well now. :)

Comment: @AlexThornton: try dates that are already mentioned (the `%53` variant fails): 2017-1-1, 2014-12-28, 2000-12-31. The calendar repeats itself every 400 years: you could try all dates